# Amazon EC2 - launching AMI by default

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've recently completed a project using EC2 for hosting, problem is it keeps launching an AMI when I terminate my running instance. How do I prevent this from happening? I dont' want any running instances.

I've looked through the documentation and kind find an solution (It's probably really obvious).

Comment: do you have anything in cloudwatch to make sure so many instances are running?

Comment: I'm not using cloudwatch, what I want to do is not have any instances running.

Comment: Look in you account for an Auto Scaling group configured with a minimum number of instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have configured Auto Scaling. All you have to do is either deleting the Auto Scaling if you don't need it or modify the auto scaling group to let the minimum and desired sizes equal 0 as below

```
as-update-auto-scaling-group YourAutoScalingGroup --desired-capacity 0 --min-size 0 --max-size 0 -I YourKey -S YourPassword
```

Or Delete it as below in the same order

1. Policies
2. Auto Scaling Group
3. Launch Configuration

   as-delete-policy YourPolicyName --auto-scaling-group YourAutoScalingGroup -I YourKey -S YourPassword

   as-delete-auto-scaling-group YourAutoScalingGroup --force-delete -I YourKey -S YourPassword

   as-delete-launch-config YourLaunchConfigurationName -I YourKey -S YourPassword